# 13" MacBook Air Terminal says " (base) UNKNOWN

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, command-line

Usually when I open the terminal, the first part of the command line says (base) john-doe-air, but when I opened it up today, it comes up with the following.
[image]

What should I do to rectify this issue? Thank you.

NB: For privacy reasons, I have changed the name to John Doe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UNKNOWN` part is your computer hostname, for some reasons it changed itself.

You can change the hostname from the Terminal using the following commands :

```
sudo scutil --set ComputerName "newname"
sudo scutil --set LocalHostName "newname"
sudo scutil --set HostName "newname"
```

Then flush your DNS cache with `dscacheutil -flushcache` and reboot your Mac.

You can also change it without using commands, in `System Preferences > Sharing > Computer Name`.